# Wireless SWD interface

Tags: usb, stm32, wireless, programming, microprocessor

Is it possible to have a wireless SWD interface with a simple Data and clock line like the cheap STM32 ST-Link clones.

My initial, and flawed, idea was that I would have an ST-link plugged into the USB port of my computer and on the Data and clock lines that would normally go to the target MCU i would build something that just monitors the state of the data and clock pin and send its over wireless to a receiver which in turn is plugged into the MCU and changed the data and clock lines  accordingly.

This idea may have many flaws but the main one I see is that if I am just relaying to the target the pin changes I have no idea if the Host is asking the target something and the target has to take over and relay information, at which point I need to check the state of target pins and relay that back to the host. So in other words i need to have in depth knowledge of the protocol and not simply relay pin changes back and forth??

Unless there is a simple way of figuring out which way the data should be going, like an extended clock signal or something... I do not know the protocol well enough.

This idea stemmed from wireless transmitting serial data which is easy, but anything else gets a bit more complex. Also stems from a product that I just saw that does the same but uses a Wifi connection to debug and program.

So the question boil down to is it possible the way I am describing of just checking pin states and transmitting that and having it mimicked on the other end or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There won't be an *easy* solution to your problem except for the obvious things like using a wireless USB hub (even these don't work too well for some things, I tried running a sensor suite for real time data collection and wireless usb has some failings and connection problems).

The SWD would be difficult to transmit over wireless, since it's a two wire bus and bi-directional, this means that a wireless "bridge" would have to have some micro controllers that could talk to each other at a much higher rate than the SWD bus. Wireless modules are available for SPI, but not for I2C.

The easiest thing to do would be to run a raspberri pi or some other computer with GDB or this [module that uses a GDB](https://www.tindie.com/products/scdoubleu/arm-cortex-m-wifi-enabled-swdjtag-debugger/) server with wifi.

Comment: wow that little board is NICE!!!! too bad its retired!!